# Mura cms 5.4 adding menu item to top level navigation

Tags: coldfusion, mura

I'm new to Mura cms and working on version 5.4. I need to add a new menu item to top level navigation. How do i do that? The exisiting site has home, products, about us, contact us as the primary menu items. Now i need to add two more menu items. However I search I can't find a proper answer to this. Nowhere in the code or admin panel do I see the existing menu items. Really feeling clueless over this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Verified all that stuff but unable to figure how to do it. Can anyone please elaborate on the method of doing this? Where do i see the exisiting menu items?

Answer (score 0):

In Mura CMS, the top level navigation is constructed from the children of the Home page. So what you need to do is add a page under need the Home page in the Site Manager and it will automatically appear in the top level navigation.

Comment: Thank you Guust for answering. i tried adding a page under the home in site manager and that seemed to override the contents of the home page instead of appearing as a menu item.now this page takes over the home page.

Comment: Did you add the page as described in the following guide? http://docs.getmura.com/user-guide/working-with-content/adding-content/

Comment: i tried that and made a copy of about_us and it made copy of all the pages multiple times and not letting me to delete. im the super admin for the site but i cannot delete these pages. i tried to clear the version history but that didnt help. i didnt publish these pages but the status shows they are already published. this is soo confusing. thank you

Comment: When making a copy of a page this page is by default set to not display. You can change this by changing the value of 'Display' when editing a page.

Comment: but the display says yes and nav also set to yes. can you please tell me how i can delete the extra copies it made. please

Comment: the delete button is grayed out for these pages

Comment: you've created a seperate issue for the problem when deleting the pages: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549941/how-to-delete-a-page-in-mura

Comment: When on a child of the home page 'Display' is set to 'Yes' and 'Include in Site Navigation' is checked it still doesn't appear in the site navigation, the theme might be using some custom code to display the site navigation. Without access to the code it's impossible to solve your problem.

Comment: thank you Guust for the help. i created another issue for deleting the pages hoping to get an answer so i can delete the extra pages before they get noticed onthe site. but looks like my day is bad.no answers

Comment: Any answers to this greatly appreciated. i have tried verifying the html_head, header.cfm.when i added the page and set nav to yes and display to yes it updated the links in the footer but not in the header. following is the code segments

Comment: <div id="footerLinks" style="float: left;">