# How to delete a page in Mura

Tags: coldfusion, mura

I tried the copy all option in the Mura CMS 5.4 admin in order to create another menu item in the top level navigation. It created multiple copies of the same pages. I would like to delete some of those pages but it is not allowing me to. The red cross seems to be grayed out.  When I went to version history to see if I could delete all of the versions there but it would not allow me. Now the status also shows it is published. How do I delete those pages? I have admin permissions for this site. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

go to the "Advanced" tab (or maybe one of the other ones) ... see if you can find a "Lock Node" option. Maybe it is checked/selected? If so, deselect it, Publish and then you should be able to delete it.